# Blocking sort operators

Tags: sorting, join

I am currently reading about blocking operators in sorts and joins, and I have couple questions, that cannot find any proper explanation

- Is mergejoin a blocking operator?
- Should any sort operator be blocking necessarily?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about practical programming, but CS concepts. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every sort algorithm is necessarily blocking because the last input item could be the first output item. It is therefore never possible to emit output items before consuming the last input item. (Except if an input item happens to be the smallest possible value of its data type.)

Merge join and the other merge-based operators are not blocking because they can output items as soon as they have read just a small constant number of items.